# Watchlist matching query does not exist

Tags: django

Iam trying to find out if a movie exists on the watchlist on my movie project and this error occured while i goes to detail page of a movie that doesn't exists in watchlist, how can i solve this?

this is the code.

this is my Watchlist model

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
movie=models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)
date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
def __str__(self):
return self.movie.name
```

this is my movie detail request function on views.py

```
def view_movie(request,mslug):
user=request.usermovie=Movie.objects.get(slug=mslug)
watchlist=Watchlist.objects.get(user=user,movie__slug=mslug)
return render(request,'moviesingle.html',{'mov':movie,'watchlist':watchlist})
```

this is the movie detail template

```
<div class="social-btn">
{% if watchlist.is_none %}
<a href="{% url 'Watchlist:add_watchlist' mov.id %}" class="parent-btn">
<i class="ion-plus"></i> Add to Watchlist</a>
{% else %}
<a href="" class="parent-btn">
<i class="ion-heart"></i> Already in Watchlist</a>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

while going to a movie that exists on the watchlsit, its showing 'Already on watchlist', the problem is with the movies not in watchlist..

Answer (score 0):

There's no is_none method implemented for querysets
instead you can check if the qs is empty with: `{% if not watchlist.exists %}`

Comment: you're  you can mark this as answer so other people can rely on it